# Array index value on clicking a checkbox - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, checkbox

I have JSON array which has 2 check boxes. On Clicking a checkbox i need to get array index of clicked checkbox. Any help would be appreciated

data.json

```
"contents" : [
    {
        "title" : "Book1",
        "type" : "CHECKBOX"
    },
    {
        "title" : "Book2",
        "type" : "CHECKBOX"
    }
]
```

templates.json

```
{
"checkboxTemplate": "<div style='width:15px'><input type='checkbox' id='myCheck' onClick='myFunction()'></div>"
}
```

In Controller data.json is read and stored it in datalist array.

```
    function myFunction() {

      var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
      for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++) {
            if (checkBox.checked == true){
                alert("Checked");
             }
                else
                {
                    alert("Unchecked");

                }
            }
      }
```

HTML

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="ContentCtrll as ctrll">
    <content-item ng-repeat="item in ctrll.content" content="item">
    </content-item>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more code!

Comment: Please add the HTML code that renders your checkbox, your click handler for the checkbox. Where does the checkBox variable come from in your for loop?

Comment: What is HTML of your checkboxes?

Comment: Inside the function that turns the contents array into rendered checkboxes, add some code that will set the id or a data attribute on the checkbox that contains the index of the array element. If the rendered checkboxes are contained inside a seperate wrapper, the index of the checkbox isnide the childNodes of its parent element will also match the index inside the array.

Comment: If "datalist array contains JSON array" as you state, then `dataList.length` would not work. JSON is **text**. `dataList` would be a string. You'd have to run JSON.parse() on it before you could use it. So no, dataList is not a "JSON array", it's a JavaScript array. Please understand the difference and use the correct terminology. Read the blurb for the ["json" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) and note the point about JSON vs JS literals. You might think it's pedantic but if you're going to use a technical term, you ought to use it correctly. I've edited your question

Comment: Anyway it's unclear how the array relates in any way to your checkboxes...do the checkboxes have some attribute which is comparable to the content of the array? e.g. an Id or data-attribute maybe? As others requested, please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: You templates.json suggests that you're using duplicate ids, which is invalid HTML and **must be fixed.**

Comment: To make it more clear: You cannot have two or more elements in a page sharing the same `id` value.